# How do I create a CSV file with a dictionary and only using variables as keys and values

Tags: python, dictionary, variables, append, key

I need to do some real estate market research and for this in need the prices, and other values from new houses.

So my idea was to go on the website where i get the information.
Go to the Main-Search-Site and scrape all the RealEstateIDs that would navigate me directly to the single pages for each house where i can than extract my infos that i need.
Right now I get all the data that i want for each house but just as raw data in `print()`. I want to save it all in a .csv file and i my approach was to use a dictionary file.
Since im quiet new to Python it would be great if you could help me and explain me my mistake.

The csv.file should look like this in the end:

```
IDS Price  Size District  Flattyp  Rooms
123  1200  250  Hollywood  good     4
253  25       Beverly Hills bad     2
952
```

Code:

```
res = requests.get('https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/S-T/Wohnung-Kauf/Nordrhein-Westfalen/Duesseldorf/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/true?enteredFrom=result_list')
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
r = re.compile(r'resultListModel:(.*)')
data = soup.find('script', text=r).text
script = r.findall(data)[0].rstrip(',')
#resultListModel:
results = json.loads(script)
ids = list(results['searchResponseModel']['entryInformation'].keys())

data = json.dumps(ids)
houseinfo = {}

csvData = [['id','purchasePrice','Spacesize','District','Flattyp','Rooms']]

def get_house_info (House):
    for id in ids:
        try:
            sourceCode = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/' + str(id)).read()
            purchasePrice = str(sourceCode).split('"purchasePrice":')[1].split(',"geoCode"')[0]
            Spacesize = str(sourceCode).split('"area":')[1].split('},"details"')[0]
            District = str(sourceCode).split('"quarter":')[1].split('},')[0]
            Flattyp = str(sourceCode).split('"is24qa-typ grid-item three-fifths">')[1].split('</dd> </dl> <dl class')[0]
            Rooms = str(sourceCode).split('is24qa-zimmer grid-item three-fifths"> ')[1].split(' </dd> </dl> <dl class=')[0]
            #parking_space = str(sourceCode).split('<dd class="is24qa-garage-stellplatz grid-item three-fifths">')[1].split('</dd> </dl>')[0]
            #parking_price = str(sourceCode).split('<dd class="is24qa-garage-stellplatz-kaufpreis grid-item three-fifths">')[1].split('</dd> </dl> </div>')[0]
            #print(id, purchasePrice, Spacesize, Flattyp, Rooms, District,)

            houseinfo [id]= {'price' : purchasePrice, 'size' : Spacesize,
                             'district': District, 'flattyp' : Flattyp,
                             'rooms': Rooms};

            with open ('house.csv', 'a') as csvData:
                writer = csv.writer(csvData)
                writer.writerow(houseinfo)

            csvData.close()

        except Exception as e:
            print("failed in the main loop", str(e))

get_house_info(ids)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're very close.  Since it looks like you already have a dictionary called houseinfo, which for each id has a dictionary of a particular format I'd recommend doing something like

```
with open('foo.txt', 'w') as csvfile:
    cols = ['price', 'size', 'district', 'flattyp', 'rooms']
    dict_result = {'price': 1.0, 'size': 1, 'district': 'Hollywood', 'flattyp': 'good', 'rooms': 3}
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=cols)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(dict_result)
```

where dict_result is your `houseinfo[id]`.

This results in a text file of

```
price,size,district,flattyp,rooms
1.0,1,Hollywood,good,3
```

Which you can then read using the csvreader.